# Load a video passed into the URL by name

Tags: html

I am trying to get one of many video files that resides on the server to play on a Web Page using HTML or HTML5.  It should run based on whatever filename is passed into the url via an argument. This is the code I have so far, but it does not work.

Example:   www.mysite.com?video=myVideo.mp4
So myvideo.mov would reside in the folder on the server.  I want the parameter video equal to the video filename.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onLoad="GetVideo()">

<div style="width: 100%; height: 768px;  controls Autoplay=autoplay; overflow: hidden;">
 <video id="video" width="100%" loop autoplay controls>
  <source id="#videoSource" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
 </video>
</div>

<script>
function GetVideo() {
     x = getUrlVars()["video"];
     document.querySelector("#videoSource").setAttribute("src", x);
}

function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Expected results would be:
run this URL sample:

www.mysite.com?video=myvideo.mp4

It should play the video file "myvideo.mp4" that resides in the site folder on the server.

---

Updated sample - This is more what I want it to do - I took recommendations below, but the following DOES NOT WORK.  I am trying to get this to work on all browsers:

Example:   www.mysite.com?video=myVideo.mp4&folder=myFolder

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <div style="width:100%;overflow: hidden;">
    <video width="100%" controls>
       <source src='about:blank' type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>

<script>

function loadVideo() { 
  var player = document.querySelector('video');
  var base = 'http://ercx.natfas.com/';

  var videoFile = getUrlVars()["video"];
  var folder = getUrlVars()["folder"];

  if (${folder} = "") {
    player.src = '${base}${videoFile}';
  } else {
    player.src = '${base}${folder}/${videoFile}';
  }
  player.load();
  player.play();
}

function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}

loadVideo();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You've (0) got a missing `"` in the opening body tag. When this is fixed, `x` in GetVideo gets the correct value. Not sure what you're trying to do though with `document.videoSource = x;` - that's where your problem lies.

Comment: `<video>` tag doesn't play `.mov` files so convert it into MP4 and/or WebM

Comment: Why would you strip urls they need the exact characters. They will no longer point to the location of the files. I don't see how this is usable...Of course it isn't going to work in any browser. A browser needs valid url not stripped strings of crap

Comment: Have you looked what `getUrlVars()` returns? As it is now you should get error because it's mangled...`/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, `  <== where's the rest of it? If this is going to be your livelihood you gotta be more careful

Comment: I just found another error that's not a victim of hack and paste ... Go to https://jshint.com

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onLoad="GetVideo()">

<div style="width: 100%; height: 768px;  controls Autoplay=autoplay; overflow: hidden;">
 <video id="video" width="100%" loop autoplay controls>
  <source id="videoSource" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
 </video>
</div>

<script>
function GetVideo() {
    x = getUrlVars()["video"];
    document.querySelector("#videoSource").setAttribute("src", x);
}

function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Looks like it's achieving what we want to? =)

[image: Example run]---

--- Old

You need to set the source correct on the video element, i.e.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

So in your case:

```
function GetVideo() {
    x = getUrlVars()["video"];
    document.querySelector("#videoSource").setAttribute("src", x);
}
```

Also you're missing a " on the line:

```
<body onLoad="GetVideo()>
```

Comment: Do you get a JavaScript error, or some more info the continue with?

Comment: Updated the answer with running example.

Comment: hmmm, I tried using your latest sample and it is still not working.  I just get a blank video window.

It won't let me paste in the code here... says it is too long.

Comment: I used your code.  Placed a test.mp4 in the server folder.  Then tried passing a ?video=test.mp4 at the end of my URL and I still get a blank video window with no errors

Comment: I just tested this on Safari and it is working.  On Chrome it is just showing a black video panel.

Comment: Is this HTML or HTML5 ?   If it is HTML5, is that why it is failing on Chrome?   I want it to work on all browsers...

Comment: You can find the browser compability for the video tag here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp That's probably not the problem. If you hard code the value (src to the video file) to the video element - does it work then?

Comment: Hi Tibbelit, I will need to dig into it when I get back in town.  I really appreciate your help!  What we have here works great in Safari and IE.  It fails in Chrome.   I would guess it is a parameter issue in Chrome that is failing.  I will check back in the week after next.  Thank you so much for your help!!!

Comment: I tested this on IE and it also worked well.  It failed on Chrome on both the Mac and on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

## Video File Array

1. First you need to use [MP4](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats#MP4_H.264_(AAC_or_MP3)), [Ogg](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats#Ogg_Theora_Vorbis) and/or [WebM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats#WebM). Do not use MOV (as mentioned in question). If you got Safari to play a MOV through a `<video>` tag, it means you have [a plugin](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/AudioandVideoTagBasics/AudioandVideoTagBasics.html#pageTitle) that facilitates doing so:

   1. Never assume a user has a plugin or assume a user will download and install one if advised to do so.
   2. [The majority of the world uses PC not Macs](https://www.thurrott.com/hardware/66933/mac-nears-10-percent-usage-share).
2. Assuming that all videos are in one location (as was stated in question), make an array of their file names:

> ```
> var files = ['005609.mp4', '005610.mp4', '005612.mp4'];
> ```

3. Next, store your path into a variable:

> ```
> var base = 'https://storage04.dropshots.com/photos6000/photos/1381926/20170326/';
> ```

4. Declare an index number and reference the `<video>` tag:

> ```
> var index = 0;
> var player = document.querySelector('video');
> ```

5. Process the array with `.map()` and interpolate each element in the array with the `base` (see `function loadVideo()` in demo).
6. If you want to play your files one after another, do not use the `[loop]` attribute (as indicated in HTML of question). Instead register the `<video>` tag to the `ended` event and increment the `index` (see eventListener at the end of demo).

Also a `<div>` cannot play videos, therefore `[controls]` and `[autoplay]` attributes are unnecessary on a `<div>` (pertaining to the HTML in question).

---

### Demo

This video player will load automatically (as indicated in the HTML of question).

```js
var player = document.querySelector('video');
var base = 'https://storage04.dropshots.com/photos6000/photos/1381926/20170326/';
var files = ['005609.mp4', '005610.mp4', '005612.mp4'];
var index = 0;

function loadVideo(host, array, index) {
  
  var urls = array.map(function(vid, idx) {
    return `${host}${vid}`;
  });

  player.src = urls[index];
  player.load();
  player.play();
}

player.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
  
  if (index >= files.length) {
    index = 0;
    loadVideo(base, files, index);
  } else {
    loadVideo(base, files, index);
  }
  index++;
});

loadVideo(base, files, index);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <div style="width:480px;overflow: hidden;">
    <video width="100%" controls>
  <source src='about:blank' type="video/mp4">
 </video>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the sample.  I really don't want to have to maintain the list of video files in the folder... there could be 1000s.   I really want to pass the filename in as a parameter.  Can this be done in HTML that will work on all browsers?

Comment: Oh you want to type a filename manually? The function will handle 1 to ....n `var files = ['single.mp4']`

Comment: What would your sample look like if I passed the filename?  Ultimately I would like to pass 2 parameters.  The first would be the folder name, the second would be the filename.  So then it would stitch the 2 together.  This way I can keep all of the videos categorized in folders.    Something like this:
ie.   www.mysite.com?folder=outdoor&video=single.mp4

Comment: Like `var host = "https://www.example.com"` `var path = "?folder=outdoor&video="` `var file = "single.mp4"`? Sure, I don't see why not. `host` being a constant of course.

Comment: Everything can be constant except the folder and video file being passed in. Folder will be passed in and Video will be passed in as arguments in the URL. Thanks!

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work in Chrome. Can you generate a sample that would work in all browsers ?   I need it to accept 2 parameters in the URL...  the folder and the video file to play.   The folder resides on the server in the root of the site. The video file will reside in that folder.   ie. www.mysite.com?folder=myFolder&video=VideoFileSample.mp4

Comment: I'm using Chrome and It works in this post. It's three real urls pointing to a three real MP4s that reside within a real server. You'll need to give me a real url to test preferably the one you can't get to work. Perhaps you need to be really careful with how you cut and paste (have you taken a closer look on how mangled your question is?)

Comment: I need your sample code to accept 2 parameters.  One for folder and one for video.  Your demo loops through videos in an array on the server not accepting any parameters. That will not work for me.  I do not see any mangling on my side.  I am using Chrome on a Mac...   Is there a way for us to chat?   The server is IIS Windows server, so I can't give you access to it..  When I type in this comment window, it limits me to not many characters.  I cannot paste a sample here... it won't let me.

Comment: Please see the latest sample I put at the top... this sample does not work on any browser.

Comment: First where are you getting these fragments? Are they from a 3rd party is that why you are stripping them? The urls are just strings and you are over processing them. Are you trying to say that you will receive dynamic input that changes drastically? You gave me the impression that the content was yours and you won't need to use more than one file at a time.

Comment: Why would you strip urls they need the exact characters ur they will no longer point to the location of the files. I don't see how this is usable...Of course it isn't going to work in any browser. A browser wou;f need valid urld not stripped dtrings of crap.

Comment: I'm not sure where you are talking about stipping the URLs.  I am trying to build the URL based on the base + the folder if there is one + the video file to play.

Comment: `getUrlVars()` returns **pieces** of the original url when you add those pieces to the base the url will look like this: `http://ercx.natfas.com/animals/fish.mp4`  from: `http://ercx.natfas.com/?&folder=animals&video=fish.mp4` if the original url works why a new one? Are you for certain the new one would even work? and where are you running this? Not from the client it'd be locally.

Comment: I think I see what you are saying.

Comment: I think I see what you are saying.  Clients are not running locally.  They can run this from a browser or from within my desktop application.  You are correct that it is reconstructingvthe url to the mp4.  I want the video to play in a player in the browser.  Not download and run it.  I want to put other things on the screen after I get through this.  Originally I was running it with no base url.  It was just using the folder/video.  Looking at your sample, I thought I needed the URL path to the video.  I think this is getting way over complicated.  Stack Overflow won’t let me say much here...

Comment: These comments are super limited on what I can respond.  If I accidentally press enter and edit it, it won’t save because of the 5 minute limit.  Very frustrating...

Comment: Just got back from vacation...  guess it looks like this question should just get deleted.  Not sure how to ask it without being confusing.  I was just looking for a simple webpage to host a video that I tell the page exactly what folder and file to play....  This appears to be a confusing question.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Tibbelit as the closest to working.  It doesn't work on Chrome but it seems to work on other browsers.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onLoad="GetVideo()">

<div style="width: 100%; height: 768px;  controls Autoplay=autoplay; overflow: hidden;">
 <video id="video" width="100%" loop autoplay controls>
  <source id="videoSource" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
 </video>
</div>

<script>
function GetVideo() {
    x = getUrlVars()["video"];
    document.querySelector("#videoSource").setAttribute("src", x);
}

function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```